# Push values to array but as object? JS

Tags: javascript

I need to push to array of object no array. Check my code..I don;t know where is my problem here

```
    this.trainingPlan?.trainingTemplateExercises.push(this.singleTrainingInfo.trainingExercises.map(obj => {
      return obj
    }))
```

in this situation i push array of object. I need to push only object.
Like now i push [{obj...} , {obj2...}]

i need to push only {obj...} , {obj2...}

I need to push only object here..

This is now array like a

[ 0: [ obj1 , obj2]]

Comment: Use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) instead of `map`.

Comment: Can you provide me code ?

Comment: There are numerous examples in the documentation I linked. Make an attempt at implementing it and if you're still having troubles, I'll be happy to help.

Comment: I can't understand....i can only to + and - :D

Answer (score 0):

Your map here doesn't really do anything. It's just returning the same array you're mapping in the first place. Just concat the two arrays.

```
this.trainingPlan?.trainingTemplateExercises = this.trainingPlan?.trainingTemplateExercises.concat(this.singleTrainingInfo.trainingExercises)
```

Comment: Okay David can you  show me how to do this with reduce. answear of @DigitalDrifter me very interesting ...

Comment: Honestly I'm not sure where he's going with that. I'll admit I'm unfamiliar with reduce, but my understanding of it differs.

Comment: David this is work and good is...but @DigitalDrifter very interested me about him solution with reduce...